# Jquery mobile headers and footers bouncing around

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, footer

I have fixed headers and footers on my webapp. But I am always getting problems (as you can see in picture) then I am focusing on the input fields. Same problem with headers...This makes my web app look terrible.

I was looking around for some solution, but could not find anything working. Hopefully someone has solution which could help for others also.

Here id footer div attributes:

```
 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">
```

[image: footer fails]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have  data-position="fixed"  duplicated. Check this page for more info http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html